# foreach doparallel on GPU

Tags: r, foreach, gpu, doparallel

I have this code for writing my results in parallel. I am using **foreach** and **doParallel** libraries in R.

```
    output_location='/home/Desktop/pp/'
    library(foreach)
    library(doParallel)
    library(data.table)

    no_cores <- detectCores()
    registerDoParallel(makeCluster(no_cores))
    a=Sys.time()

    foreach(i=1:100,.packages = c('foreach','doParallel')
    ,.options.multicore=mcoptions)%dopar% 
    {result<- my_functon(arg1,arg2)
    write(result,file=paste(output_location,"out",toString(i),".csv"))
    gc()
    }
```

Now it uses 4 cores in the CPU and thus the writing takes very less time using this code.But i want foreach-doparallel using GPU. Is there any method for processing the **foreach** **doParallel** loop on GPU. **gputools,gpuR** are some GPU supporting R packages. But they are mainly for mathematical computations like gpuMatMult(),gpuMatrix() etc. I am looking for running the loop on GPU. Any help or guidance will be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parallelization with `foreach` or similar tools works because you have multiple CPUs (or a CPU with multiple cores), which can process multiple tasks at once. A GPU also has multiple cores, but these are already used to *process a single task in parallel*. So if you want to parallelize further, you will need *multiple GPUs*.

However, keep in mind that GPUs are faster than CPUs only for certain types of applications. Matrix operations with large matrices being a prime example! See the performance section [here](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/introducing-rcpparrayfire/) for a recent comparison of one particular example. So it might make sense for you to consider if the GPU is the right tool for you.

In addition: File IO will *always* go via the CPU.

Comment: thanks @Ralf Stubner. I have only one Gpu with multiple core. So i cant go for foreach parallel using GPU. right?

Comment: @Aswathy Yes, that's true.